# Facing Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, string-parsing

I am trying to develop a login app in which I am facing some problems. I looked for solutions to these at various places but couldnt find any.

The errors are:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help.

My login.java class :

```
public class Login extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
Button bLogin;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.15.103/login.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            }

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                //Options.PHONE=username;
                Intent ii = new Intent(Login.this,NewActivity.class);
                //here Options.class is the activity where we will move once login is authenticated.
                startActivity(ii);
                //finish();
                // this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current
                // activity now! Moving to other activity



                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
}
```

My JSONParser.java class:

```
    public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj ;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

// Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
// Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

// Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

// Close the input stream.
            is.close();
// Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

// Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

// Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }

    // function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

// Making HTTP request
        try {

// check for request method
            if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
// request method is POST
// defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

// try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

// return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Login.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="118dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:text="Login" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="Enter username"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter password"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devikanigam.login" 
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion=""
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewActivity"
            android:label="Login">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat :

```
06-24 16:33:49.315    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-24 16:33:49.395    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.devikanigam.login is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-24 16:33:49.399    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
06-24 16:33:49.419    3364-3371/com.devikanigam.login I/art﹕ Debugger is active
06-24 16:33:49.608    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
06-24 16:33:49.609    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:49.826    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:50.035    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:50.245    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:50.454    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:50.664    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:50.874    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:51.084    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:51.294    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:51.505    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:51.715    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:51.925    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:52.135    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 16:33:52.346    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1351)
06-24 16:33:52.399    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-24 16:33:52.431    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0fdf20, tid 3364
06-24 16:33:52.437    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-24 16:33:52.517    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae088de0, tid 3383
06-24 16:33:52.541    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-24 16:33:52.616    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-24 16:33:52.637    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 16:33:52.637    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c4bc20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 16:34:09.066    3364-3384/com.devikanigam.login D/request!﹕ starting
06-24 16:34:09.112    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 16:34:09.112    3364-3383/com.devikanigam.login W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa56281c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 16:34:09.540    3364-3376/com.devikanigam.login I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3906(194KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 55% free, 832KB/1856KB, paused 22.484ms total 152.752ms
06-24 16:34:09.633    3364-3384/com.devikanigam.login E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-24 16:34:09.634    3364-3384/com.devikanigam.login E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.devikanigam.login, PID: 3364
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.devikanigam.login.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:110)
            at com.devikanigam.login.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:70)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-24 16:34:11.366    3364-3364/com.devikanigam.login E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.devikanigam.login.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{200d5161 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,232} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.devikanigam.login.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:84)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.devikanigam.login.Login.onClick(Login.java:57)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-24 16:34:12.806    3364-3384/com.devikanigam.login I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3364 SIG: 9
```

Login.php :

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","divy");
$db= mysqli_select_db($conn,"users");
$password=$_POST["password"];
$username=$_POST["username"];

if (!empty($_POST)) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
// Create some data that will be the JSON response
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Please Enter Both first Username and Password.";

//die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
//display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
//app will parse
die(json_encode($response));
}
$query = " SELECT * FROM yardusers WHERE username = '$username'and password ='$password'";

$sql1=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
if (!empty($row)) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Present, this username is already in use";
die(json_encode($response));
}
else{

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Invalid Username or Password.";
die(json_encode($response));
}
}
else{

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "One or both fields are empty";
die(json_encode($response));
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Make sure that the address `http://192.168.15.103/login.php` is accessible from your testing device. Try to open it in your device's browser if it connects than ok otherwise you have to configure your device properly to communicate with this server

Comment: yes it is accessible from my android emulator.

Comment: Then you have problem in your `login.php` script

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the php response on a web browser

Comment: Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post the screenshot

Comment: The reponse is:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: password in D:\wamp\www\login.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 245392 {main}( ) ..\login.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\wamp\www\login.php on line 5
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 245392 {main}( ) ..\login.php:0
{"success":0}

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to send json to webservice..

```
public static void NetworkCall()
        {
            String url = "http://.../.../JsonBL.svc/...";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));


            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            OutputStream out = null;

            out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(CreateJson.jsonObject.toString());
            writer.close();
            out.close();

        }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }


    }
```

and to create json object u can use the following code..

```
static JsonObject jsonObject;

    public static void writeJson(ArrayList<JsonObjectClass> object) {

        jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        String albumName = object.get(0).album_name.substring(0,object.get(0).album_name.indexOf(" "));

        jsonObject.addProperty("CataLogName",albumName);
        jsonObject.addProperty("CreatedBy", object.get(0).license_key);
        jsonObject.addProperty("StDate", object.get(0).album_opened);
        jsonObject.addProperty("EdDate", object.get(0).album_closed);
        jsonObject.addProperty("latitude", object.get(0).lattitue);
        jsonObject.addProperty("longitude", object.get(0).longitude);}
```

This works perfect for me.. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: can you plz tell me which part of code to edit ??
and where is the problem in my code ??